# What is the difference between blender render and blender game?

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have to simulate rigid body physics simulation that is close to the real objects. Its about free fall of objects from initial random position onto a table.

I am new to blender so I started my project in blender render and have been working on it. But I see that in certain [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGAwRKPlpCw), they use blender engine. So I wasn't quite sure about the difference of these two modes.

When to use which? What is right setting for my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are making a still render or animation, then you most likely want to use the [rigid body physics in the 3D view](http://blender.org/manual/physics/rigid_body/introduction.html).

If you are making a game or a program that users will interact with in some way, then you most likely want the [game engine](http://blender.org/manual/game_engine/physics/introduction.html).

---

[Not too long ago](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Rigid_Body_Simulation#Blender_2.66:_Rigid_Body_Simulation) blender didn't have any way to simulate rigid body physics outside of the game engine, and there are still lots of tutorials floating around from before that time.